# Call PHP with the same name of the directory the file is in

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This may sound like a strange question.  :-)

I've some directories: inside every directory there's an index.php file, so when you access http://mywebsite.com/mydirectory the index.php of that directory is requested.

For some reason I need a different thing: the name of the file must be the same of the directory, so, for example, if I have the docs directory, the file requested must be the one named docs.php.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Did you look for htaccess (url rewrite)?

Comment: Of course but I wanted to know if there is some php magics to reach the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

Make a .htaccess file with the line

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```